# How to send joi validation error in API response

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I want to send joi validation error in response how can I do this
here is my code but it is not working,

File **mainfile.js**

```
const { loginSchema } = require("./helper/validate_schema.js");

var loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    let result = await loginSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
    console.log(result)
    res.json({Error:result})
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

File **validate_schema.js**

```
const joi = require('joi');

const loginSchema = joi.object({
    email:joi.string().email().required(),
    password:joi.string().min(5).required()
})


module.exports={loginSchema}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write a validate function using schema:

```
function validate(req) {
  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: joi.string().email().required(),
    password: joi.string().min(5).required(),
  });
  return Joi.validate(req, schema); 
}
```

then inside post route:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  // check the error object first 
  console.log(error)
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);    
  // if not error write your logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I putted the example of true way from latest Joi version
hope is helpful

```
app.post('/api/courses',(req,res) => {
const schema = Joi.object({name:Joi.string().min(3).required()})
const result = schema.validate(req.body);
if(result.error ) {
// 400 Bad Request 
res.status(400).send(result.error);
return;
}

const course = {
    id:courses.length +1,
    name:req.body.name
}
courses.push(course);
res.send(course)})
```